# Difference between C: and C:/

Tags: java, windows

I was just reading some java book and making some small programs for practice, I created a small code to get information about the path I entered, and the code is:

```
String path = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Path to analyze");

File file =  new File(path);

if (file.exists())
{
    String result = "";
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        result += "Path is directory\n ";
        String [] resList = file.list();

        for (String s : resList)
        {
            result += s + ", ";
        }
    }
    if (file.isFile())
    {
        result += "Path is a file\n";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
```

Now in the input dialogue, when I enter `C:`, the result is `build, build.xml, manifest.mf, nbproject, src`, but when I enter C:/, it shows the complete list of directories and files in C.

And strangely it does not happen with the D drive and other drives (i.e. the result is same for D:/ and D:), what is happening please explain?

**Update**
Same happens in WPF using C#!

Comment: What is the desired result?  Insure or remove the `/` from your path, based on the result you really want.

Comment: No desired result, I was just writing code for practice

Comment: @NiklasB Microsoft Windows uses backslashes.  This is most likely Linux/Unix.

Comment: So why are you putting forward slashes then?

Comment: @Robert: Windows doesn't really care if you give it `/`s or `\\`s

Comment: Forward slashes are for switches, not for folder separators.  I've been doing this for awhile now, and I've never used forward slashes to separate folders in Windows.

Comment: @Robert: Sorry. What's your point here? At least to me it's very strange that `C:` is handled differently from `D:`. Whether you use forward slashes or not is very irrelevant here.

Comment: Forward or back slash gives correct info (i have checked both after you mentioned it) i.e. files and directories in the drive, but no slash is not giving the correct result for C drive only

Comment: The `File` API will silently convert forward slashes to backward slashes when the current OS is Windows. Check `java.io.Win32FileSystem#normalize()` method which is called by `java.io.File` constructors. But Windows itself, e.g. in command prompt, really doesn't eat forward slashes for example to navigate through folders.

Comment: @BalusC: It treats them like backslashes on my machine (XP SP3). The only thing that doesn't work is changing the drive like in `cd /d C:/windows`. `cd /d C:\windows/system32` works fine, though.

Comment: Wait a minute folks... since the first DOS version I used, `C:` meant **current working directory on C:**, whereas `C:\ ` meant **the root directory of `C:`**

Comment: @Niklas: ah interesting. Windows is a somewhat odd OS anyway.

Comment: @Balus What kind of franken Windows are you running? Every windows I know of accepts `/` just fine, the Win32 API does, the commandline as well and explorer too. The "save working directory of every partition" has also been true for as long as I can remember - actually quite handy if you want to avoid some push/pops.

Comment: @BalusC The `File` API may in fact convert forward slashes to backward slashes when running on Windows, but this is unnecessary because Windows does this itself. Windows has converted '/' to '\' since the old DOS days. However, '\' is *most definitely* preferred. There is really no reason to use '/'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`C:` means "whatever directory is currently selected on drive `C:`". In your case, it's probably the directory that your application is running from.

`D:` is the same as `D:/` in your case because the root directory *is* the current working directory in `D:`.

Comment: Windows definitely tracks the CWD on every drive separately, and in addition to that tracks the current working drive. The combination of those two is what you know as CWD on a *nix.

Comment: @Marko: Yes, I just checked in a `cmd.exe` and noticed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the current directory the project is running from because the result in case of C: is exactly the files and folders in the project folder! One comment said this behavior cannot be repeated on Windows 7 (that comment has probably been removed), so probably it is only specific to Windows Vista. Haven't checked on any other version of Windows though.

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine: I doubt very much that the underlying behaviour differs between Windows versions (why should they change it, seeing that it's been there for decades?). What's more likely is that it differs between JRE versions or JRE packages for the different OSs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for correction, it is most probably JRE version because and I can repeat the same thing in WPF using C#

Comment: The general behavior (tracking the last directory of every drive), exists just fine under win 7 as well: `cd d:/foo; cd c:/; cd d: # we're now in d:/foo again`

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a java question, but a windows/dos question.

The explanation comes down to the old dos command for switching drives.

Typing a drive letter followed by a colon is a command to change drives in dos, therefore the 'command' `C:` does nothing since your working dir is already on the C drive. The 'directory' returned by the native interface to the JRE is the same as if you used the path "", ie your working directory.

On the other hand, add a slash and it is a proper path, to the root of your C drive, therefore your JRE is given this directory by the native interface.

If you go to a dos command (windows>run>cmd) and type in `C:` you will see that it accepts the command but does not change directory, unless of course you are currently on a different drive at the time.

hope that helps.